# Search entire Active Directory recursively with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I'm not a very experienced VB.net user and as such, I've been trying to wrap my head around this.

I'm trying to search my Active Directory (starting from root) recursively for Computer-objects. Now, I've been able to find the computer objects in a single OU, but I want to do this for the entire AD, recursively.

```
Dim enTry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & "my.domain.com" & "/cn=Computers,dc=bla,dc=com")
    enTry.Username = "myusername"
    enTry.Password = "mypassword"
    Dim mySearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(enTry)
    mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)")
    Dim resEnt As SearchResult
```

Hope you can give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is kinda sad. I've seriously been looking for this all day, but 15 minutes after asking the question here I figured out I can just ommit the OU and it'll search from the root down. I guess that'll do.

Comment: You don't have an OU specified in your query.

Comment: You're right as 'Computers' is a container. But it may as well have been an OU. Regardless, not specifying an OU of CN does the trick.I wouldn't know how to go along with this if I had to start in an OU and recurse from there.

Comment: I don't think this question (or answer) really add anything for future visitors so I would suggest you delete it.